# Display SQL Result in label?

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Dim invoiceCount As String =
        "SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) " &
        "FROM Invoices " &
        "WHERE CustomerID = @customerID"

    Dim selectCount As New OleDbCommand(invoiceCount, connection)
    selectCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerID", customerID)

    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader2 As OleDbDataReader = selectCount.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow)

        If reader2.Read Then
            frmCustomerMaintenance.lblIncidents.Text = 'what do I put here?
        End If
        reader2.Close()
    Catch ex As OleDbException : Throw ex
    Finally : connection.Close()
    End Try
```

I've been messing with this for a while now and everything I try returns an error. I'm still fairly new to SQL in general but this needs to be done. I just want to store the result of the query in a label to show how many records the customer entered has..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to read the first column, you can just do this:

```
frmCustomerMaintenance.lblIncidents.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString()
```

However, when you are only reading a single column from a single row, like that, it's easier to just call `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader`:

```
frmCustomerMaintenance.lblIncidents.Text = selectCount.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
```

Comment: This worked easiest! Thank you. [I'll mark yours as the answer when it lets me]

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are searching for:

```
frmCustomerMaintenance.lblIncidents.Text = reader2[0].ToString()
```